# Find record either belong the main table or to the relationship eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

User table has first_name and the teacherSubjects have subject, i wan to put a condition in such a way if it matches to either the firstname in the User table or the subject in the teacherSubject

```
$teachers = User::with('teacherSubject')->whereHas('teacherSubject', function ($query) use($conditions){
                $query->where($conditions);
            })->get();
```

Comment: can you show value in $condition variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$teachers = User::with('teacherSubject')
            ->where(function($query) use($name) {
              $query->where('first_name',$name);
                    ->orWhereHas('teacherSubject', function ($query1) use($name){
                        $query1->where('subject',$name);
                    });
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
$teachers = User::where(function($sub) use($name) {
    $sub->where('first_name', $name)
    ->orWhereHas('teacherSubject', function($s) use($name) {
        $s->where('subject', $name);
    });
})whereHas('teacherSubject', function ($query) use($conditions){
$query->where($conditions);
})->with('teacherSubject')->get();
```

Here `$name` is the first name to be searched.